# how to build a c++/c project that has cmake files?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, build, cmake

I know writing codes in c/c++. But I didn't have professional experience with the languages. So I don't know the best practices of build applications.

I read some articles about CMake. I understand them. But I still don't know how I should approach a c++/c project that has CMake files, cmakelists.txt, make folder.

As an example, [github project](https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer) the project has main.CPP file, also main.c file. Both of them have the main loop in them. I also see CMake files. I know that I should compile them. What should I think when I see the project like the example, what steps should I follow?

Comment: Its usually the same approach. Create a build folder that is in a path relative to the source. change directory to that build folder. run cmake with the relative path to the source then use your build system to build using the generated makefile  or project file. This may help with the concept: [https://ecrafter.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/cmake-tutorial-part-3/](https://ecrafter.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/cmake-tutorial-part-3/)

Comment: The project tells you to do this: [https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/blob/master/INSTALL](https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/blob/master/INSTALL)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call the `MakeRelease.sh` script to build the release version.

If you want to understand how CMake and CMakeLists.txt files are created and how they should be used, the following tutorial is for you.

[Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html?highlight=dcmake_build_type)

Answer (score 0):

If you [search this repo for `main`](https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/search?q=main) you'll see that `main.c` is never referenced anymore. Looking further in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/blob/0427d31ab33f5db6fbddd19bbe1e4f5df37c2e67/CMakeLists.txt#L164) you can see that `main.cpp` is used to build the executable. You don't really need to learn the tricks of CMake to understand this.